# how to save created file to path specified in application.properties file in spring boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, rest, application.properties

I have a method which creates new file after every execution I don't want to hardcode file path in code so I added a new property in application.properties file like

> jmeter.jmx.path=D:\\PerformanceTesting\\JMXFiles\\

and instance variable which holds value like

```
  @Value("${jmeter.jmx.path}")
  private String jmxPath;
```

want to get the value of a variable inside method

```
public void saveAsJmxFile(HashTree projectTree, String fileName) throws IOException {
    //TODO 
    SaveService.saveTree(projectTree, new FileOutputStream(jmxPath+fileName+".jmx"));
}
```

its not woking for me, but if i hardcode then it i'll work.

```
public void saveAsJmxFile(HashTree projectTree, String fileName) throws IOException {
          //TODO  remove hardcoded jmxPath
           SaveService.saveTree(projectTree, new 
           FileOutputStream("D:\\PerformanceTesting\\JMXFiles\\"+fileName+".jmx"));
    }
```

Comment: Did you try debugging to see, that the value of `jmxPath` is?

Comment: You don't need to duplicate backslashes in the file config.

Comment: @Andronicus I  tried  debugging null value is coming program execution is fine but where the file is generating I cant see

Comment: @Alex I  tried it's not working for me

Comment: is the class managed by spring, annotations will not work in unmanaged classes.

Answer (score 3):

just make sure that the directory is exist

```
    Files.createDirectories(Paths.get(jmxPath));
```

i'm using java8+ nio here